# How many students are needed to assure that there are two students expected to graduate in the same year who have the same mayor?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Good morning, I have this exercise that is suppose that can be solved using the "PigeonHole Principle". After having tried it, I found that the answer was "85", however I'm not sure if I did it well. Can someone please help me to understand this exercise better?

**n=** The number I'm trying to get to. **84=** 21 majors **x** 4 groups. **2=** The two students that are expected to graduate.

n/84=2 | n-1/84=2-1 | n-1/84=1 | n-1=84 | n=84+1 | **n=85**

**Undergraduate students at a college belong to one of four
groups depending on the year in which they are expected
to graduate. Each student must choose one of 21 different majors. How many students are needed to assure that
there are two students expected to graduate in the same
year who have the same major?**

Comment: “After having tried it. I found the answer to be 85”.  In order to improve the question and attract quality answers, you  are urged to edit your post to include your complete working, including all steps, of how you got to 85.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it ;)

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow what you wrote, but the conclusion is good.  I'd phrase it as "the worst case here is if there are exactly $4$ students in each major, one for each year.  To do that needs $4\times 21=84$ students.  If you have one more than that, then you are safe."

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  For instance, you can obtain $\lfloor x \rfloor$ by typing `$\lfloor x \rfloor$ `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generalized pigeonhole principle states that if you have $kn+1$ pigeons and $n$ holes then you should have one hole with at least $k+1$ pigeons.

why?
because if you have at most $k$ pigeons in all holes then you'll have at most $kn$ pigeons.

now in this exercise you have $k=1, n=21\cdot 4=84$ because you need $k+1=1+1=2$.

so $kn+1=1\cdot 84+1=85$

So, $84$ holes and 85 pigeons.